# Azure Cognitive Search Availability and region/data center node reset/restarts

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

On July 8th we had an outage in the South Central US region for one of our Azure Search Services.  At the time the issue occurred we were running 3 replicas of the service but the health status changed to 'Degraded' and searches were failing as well as indexing operations.

Is there anyone who has experienced this or can shed light on what scenarios could cause an outage like this if the 'platform initiated downtime' occurs again?

The activity log has a 'Health Event' that contains the following:

```
"properties": {
        "title": "Not responding",
        "details": null,
        "currentHealthStatus": "Unavailable",
        "previousHealthStatus": "Available",
        "type": "Downtime",
        "cause": "PlatformInitiated"
    }
```

During this event we couldn't create a new service in that Region either. Things just hung in a 'provisioning' state.  We ended up bringing up a new service in another region but suffered the delay in re-indexing everything.

Also, does anyone know how we can be notified of these 'platform initiated downtime' events ahead of time?

Answer (score 0):

Since your service had 3 replicas so it should have been available for both read and write operations. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-performance-optimization)

You can create a "New support request" (from the Search service portal "Support + troublshooting" section at the bottom left) to ask for the root cause of the health event and what can/will be done to avoid this issue from happening in the future.